# Select2 error 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I have some issues with my select2, I'm following the example but it doesn't show the result. I use ajax to make it more simple.

**error**

```
404 (Not Found)
```

**html**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Product Name</label>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select class="productName form-control" name="productName" id="productName"></select>
   </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
public function GetCountryName(){
    $search = $this->input->get('search');
    $query = $this->datacomplete->Get_Country($search, 'name');
    echo json_encode($query);
}
```

**model**

```
class Datacomplete extends CI_Model{

    public function Get_Country($search) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->limit(10);
        $this->db->from('auto');
        $this->db->like('name', $search);
        return $this->db->get('auto')->result_array();
    }
}
```

**ajax**

```
$("#productName").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "<?php echo base_url('auto_config/GetCountryName')?>",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                search: params.term // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            var results = [];

            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                results.push({
                    id: item.id,
                    text: item.name
                });
            });
            return {
                results: results
            };
        }
    }
});
```

the error messages is 404 not found, I don't know why.

Comment: Can you confirm the HTML output of your `url: "<?php echo base_url('auto_config/GetCountryName')?>",` is actually what you expect?

Comment: Try with index.php in url `url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/auto_config/GetCountryName')?>` Also check you have set the base_url in config.php

Comment: @IsThisJavascript it's auto_config is controller name, and GetCountryName is function from controller

Comment: @Mr.ED it won't show the result, and I checked it.

Comment: have you removed "index.php" ? or try to give proper URL @ImamNur

Comment: @ankitsuthar I've finished it, thanks advice btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

**model**

```
return $this->db->get('auto')->result_array();

to

return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

**ajax**

```
url: "<?php echo base_url('auto_config/GetCountryName')?>"

to


url: "<?php echo site_url('auto_config/GetCountryName')?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here: `url: "<?php echo base_url('auto_config/GetCountryName')?>",` in your ajax. Method `GetCountryName()` in your controller should be accesible in some path, for example `/get_countries` then You can send ajax to it.

Comment: so I need to change it to `<?php echo base_url()?>./auto_config/GetCountryName`